# Drunken old puzzler

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, story

A wealthy, drunken, old-age gambler who made his fortune in bar-bets via lateral logic puzzles, various technicalities, and misleadingly-seemingly-impossible-but-actually-quite-easy-challenges climbs up onto a bar and begins to speak (and slur).

"You all  know me!"  he said "I've  had the lot of you!  But now it think I should give something back...  In this note-" he said holding up a beer mat "I've hidden a message!  Anyone who can read out the message correctly  will go into my will and inherit a portion of my vast fortune.  BUT  anyone who gets it wrong is buying the house a round!"

The beermat (in impressively legible, tiny scribbles) reads:

```
The leaps of logic that we leap, 

And leave the answers in the deep,

Beyond our mental comprehension,

Begetting much strain, strife and tension,

Yet our foes both small and great,

We truly do appreciate,

For puzzling does as puzzling is,

Whether riddle, cryptic-clues, or quiz,

The budding minds of interest growing,

Thinking, guessing until knowing,

Young and old minds charging in,

Oft knowing not where to begin,

Whether for pride or other gain,

Or just to test and grow their brain,

More worthy cause is hard to find,

Than among the puzzling kind.

ah kid vi vea id fed ed gon agaen no hope cafe rad
```

He must have been really drunk by the time he scribbled that last bit...

HINT:

> So would a hint be helpful
>     or not?
>     AH AK AA AC AP BB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the hint, we can see that:

> the last line is somehow related to the above lines. If we try indexing by the pairs (first letter is the line number, second letter is the letter in that line (ignoring spaces and punctuation)), we get "ANSWER".

Doing the same thing to the poem

> after dividing up the letters in the last line into pairs of two (`ah`, `ki`, `dv`...) gives us the solution: **SORRY BUT I SPENT IT ALL**.